# C# How to reference an inherited class from a base class

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I am trying to refernce an inherited class from a base class, here's an example of what I have:

```
public class A
{
//Some methods Here
}
public class B : A
{
//Some More Methods
}
```

I also have a `List<A>` of which I've added `B` to, and I'm trying to access `B` from. Is there a way I can get `B` from the `List<A>` I have?

Comment: foreach(B item in list.OfType<B>) DoWork(item);

Comment: Please add some detail as to what "refernce an inherited class from a base class" means in this context. As to your list question, you should investigate the method `OfType<T>()`

Comment: This sounds like something you shouldn't be trying to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have added `B` instances to `List<A>` you could cast back the item to `B`:

```
List<A> items = ...
foreach (A item in items)
{
    // Check if the current item is an instance of B
    B b = item as B;
    if (b != null)
    {
        // The current item is instance of B and you can use its members here
        ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could use the [`OfType<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method in order to get a subset of all items in the list which are instances of B:

```
List<A> items = ...
List<B> bItems = items.OfType<B>().ToList();
foreach (B item in bItems)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a property of type A and provide a constructor to assign it. You can then assing an instance of type B to that property.

```
public class A
{
      public A Child{ get; private set; }

      public A(){}

      public A( A child )
      { 
          this.Child = child;
      }
}
```

Anyway.. are you really sure that strong parent/child relation is really needed? I think you could avoid it and make everything clearer, but you should provide your real world example (or something closer to you real world usage) in order to help.